# How to suspend the autohotkey script for just one keystroke if the RSHIFT key is pressed

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following autohotkey script. I would like that (1) when I press and release the RShift, the script suspends for the next keystroke (i.e., for just one keypress) and (2) when I press and hold the RShift the script suspends until I release RShift.
Unfortunately the following code only performs (2) not (1). I am looking for a correct code to perform both (1) and (2).

```
AppsKey::RButton

RShift::Suspend, On
RShift Up::Suspend, Off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RShift::
KeyWait, RShift, T0.3
; Release RShift in less than 0,3 seconds after pressing it 
; to suspend the script for the next keystroke
If (!ErrorLevel)
{
    Suspend On
    ; BlockInput On
    SetTimer OneKeyPressed, 200
}
else
{
; Hold RShift pressed for more than 0,3 seconds 
; to suspend until you release RShift
    while GetKeyState("RShift", "P")
        Suspend On
    KeyWait, RShift, L
        Suspend, Off
}
return


#If A_IsSuspended

    RShift Up:: Suspend, Off

#If

OneKeyPressed:
If (A_TimeIdlePhysical < 100) 
{
  SetTimer OneKeyPressed, off
  ; BlockInput Off
  Suspend Off  
}
return
```

Comment: many thanks, this seems to solve the issue. let me wait for a while to have the chance of alternative answers.